# Separating GLUT animation from variable processing

Tags: glut

My question is a very simple one: say I want to run a for loop, and for each sequence of the loop I want the GLUT window to redisplay. However, I want the for loop to be separate from any GLUT method. I don't want the processing of variables which the for loop does to intersect or to be subordinated to the graphical processing functions.

Comment: Maybe use GLFW instead of GLUT? GLUT takes control of your code flow with glutMainLoop, GLFW does not. Or if you want parallel processing, use multiple threads.

Comment: "for each sequence of the loop" - you mean for each *iteration*, right? Separating some work from the GUI code should be done in a separate thread. You hand over control of your program to GLUT as soon as you call `glutMainLoop()` and essentially, program flow is only routed through registered callbacks.

Comment: Yes, I mean iteration, sorry for my taxonomical lacking. So, you say that once I run glutMainLoop() I lose control over the non-graphical program flow?

Comment: @user3228136: You can call whatever function you want from any of the GLUT callbacks, however, anything you do in the GUI thread will essentially block the GUI. It's the same with Qt and probably most if not all other GUI frameworks - no matter how powerful they are. If you have non-GUI logic to perform, do it in a worker thread and sync the GUI if necessary.

Comment: @user3228136: In case of an animation you perform at say 30Hz, i.e. you want to update stuff 30 times per second, and say rendering is running at 100Hz, i.e. if you don't block anything, you'll get 100FPS. So, you can potentially render roughly 3 times as many frames than doing animation updates, so only every 3 frames you'll actually see a new animation state. Doe that mean you should sync rendering with animation updates unconditionally? No: If another animation is running at a higher frequency and you need to render more frames to see its changes more quickly, syncing will skip parts of it.

Comment: I'm talking about synchronising rendering with the underlying data updates. For instance, when the health of my hero changes, I want this to happen separate from the event processing loop, yet I still want the GUI to be able to adapt to it (for instance - to display it be reddening or greening the health bar).

Comment: Can you please show me a very basic implementation of doing this? (Again, the example must be ultra-basic)

Comment: Does DirectX have the same issue?